# Update className on <body> on route change (on the server)

Tags: next.js, tailwind-css, app-router

In the Next.js (app router), I have a dynamic route (`app/[page]/page`) which fetches data from a CMS for each unique page. Among that data, I get a theme. I want to set that theme on the `<body>`, on the server, so that it is sent to the browser with the pre-rendered HTML.

How do I do that?

Setting the theme on the body specifically is important, so that the whole document gets the correct backgroundColor (otherwise I'd get ugly white backgrounds when I scroll beyond the top or bottom).

It seems to me, the only place to edit the <body> is in the RootLayout. But layouts don't re-render on page transitions, so I can't fetch new data here for each page.

Templates sounds promising with the "will update on each route change"-feature. But from my testing I can't have <html> and <body>-tags in a template. Or rather, if I don't have a RootLayout above it in the tree, Next tells me off and kindly creates one for me.

Updating the classList in a useEffect works, but is not ideal since the pre-rendered HTML might have a different theme, and thus will produce a flicker.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this:

```
<style jsx global>
  {`
      body {
          background: red;
       }
   `}
</style>
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**